# Changes to Drupal blocks no longer taking effect

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

I have a D6 site that I've just stumbled upon the fact that my block positions are no longer being updated. I have a given block (a Views block) that works on older pages but not newer ones. I've tried creating new blocks and they do not show up either. Old blocks are where they should be an data through Views is still being populated correctly. My site is in a state of freeze as I cannot apply some blocks to new pages. For example, the products page does not get certain blocks on creation of new products but the old products work fine. Is there someplace I can view what is going on? I've tried clearing the site cache, turning it on / off to no avail. I did notice an odd appendage to the offending block link (I should note fresh blocks do not work either)

(Doesn't work correctly)
http://www.mysite.com/admin/build/block/configure/views/c0e4f6940320aed972444b51a879c490

(Newly created block, also not working)

http://www.mysite.com/admin/build/block/configure/block/12

Answer (score 1):

please try to clear the cache first before taking any further steps

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache multiple times (see my post) through the admin (it works on other items). I'm sensing that its not effecting the correct tables.

Comment: I should also note I confirmed in the db that my cache_block table has 0 rows

Comment: ok can you change your theme to garland theme and try to turning on a new block again...(we just wanna know where is the problem it is in your theme or its happend when installing a new module)